# I programmed this SwiftUi Code for my App

Tags: xcode, swiftui

The Problem is "Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'FormStyleConfiguration' that does not accept a closure"

```
import SwiftUI

struct Stundenplan: View {
    @State private var stundenplan: [String: [String]] = [:]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                // Eingabefeld für den Tag
                Section(header: Text("Tag")) {
                    TextField("Tag (z.B. Montag)", text: "$tag")
                }

                // Eingabefeld für die Stunden
                Section(header: Text("Stunden")) {
                    TextField("Stunden (z.B. 1, 2, 3)", text: "$stunden")
                }

                // Button zum Hinzufügen des Stundenplans
                Section {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.stundenplan[self.tag] = self.stunden
                    }) {
                        Text("Stundenplan hinzufügen")
                    }
                }

                // Liste der eingetragenen Stundenpläne
                Section(header: Text("Stundenpläne")) {
                    List(stundenplan.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) { tag in
                        Text("\(tag): \(self.stundenplan[tag]!.joined(separator: ", "))")
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Stundenplan")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what is  "$tag" —> TextField("Tag (z.B. Montag)", text: "$tag")
and what is "$studen" —> TextField("Stunden (z.B. 1, 2, 3)", text: "$stunden")

you need to provide @State values here to be used in binding for TextField , like below

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var stundenplan: [String: [String]] = [:]
    @State private var tag = ""
    @State private var stunden = ""
    var body: some View {
       
        NavigationView {
            Form {
 //                Eingabefeld für den Tag
                Section(header: Text("Tag")) {
                    TextField("Tag (z.B. Montag)", text: $tag)
                }

                // Eingabefeld für die Stunden
                Section(header: Text("Stunden")) {
                    TextField("Stunden (z.B. 1, 2, 3)", text: $stunden)
                }
                
                // Button zum Hinzufügen des Stundenplans
                Section {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.stundenplan[self.tag] = self.stunden
                    }) {
                        Text("Stundenplan hinzufügen")
                    }
                }
                
                // Liste der eingetragenen Stundenpläne
                Section(header: Text("Stundenpläne")) {
                    List(stundenplan.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) { tag in
                        Text("\(tag): \(self.stundenplan[tag]!.joined(separator: ", "))")
                      
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Stundenplan")
        }
           

    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, yes, but now a new problem has occurred, with the button with "self.timetable[self.tag] = self.hours", the error "Cannot assign value of type 'String' to subscript of type '[String]'" appears.

Comment: that is a different problem though, it clearly says you are trying to equate String to type subscript, as I do not have full access to your code, I can only say , ensure you match types properly , its like Int = String is wrong , in same way such equations which have 2 different types on lhs and rhs are also wrong